# Cannot connect to On-Premises SQL Server Express Instance with go-mssqldb

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, go

I have ported a ETL utility I wrote over from C# to Go that performs a reporting task. The C# app is able to connect to the SQL Express server just fine but the Go app is struggling to find the named instance of SQLEXPRESS.

I have used both versions:

```
server=<server>\<instance>;user id=<user>;password=<passw>;database=<database>;
sqlserver://<user>:<passw>@<server>/<instance>?database=<database>
```

...in various iterations when executing:

```
db, err := sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

... and in both cases I get the the following error back:

```
no instance matching 'SQLEXPRESS' returned from host 'localhost'
```

Comment: Resolved this by enabling TCP/IP on the SQLEXPRESS Server with SQL Server Config util. It seems I made an incorrect assumption. Just because my C# application authenticated correctly with AD without the need for TCP/IP being enabled didn't mean the the Golang lib aught to be able to do the same. (If it is not inferred, I did create a SQL login when I was working with Golang).